# combining 2 select queries into one

Tags: sql, oracle

So i got a table representing friends, it has a column username1 and a column username2, and i want to get all usernames where username1 and username2 is equals something. Right now i am doing it with 2 queries:

```
SELECT username1 FROM friends WHERE username2 LIKE 'SOMETHING';
SELECT username2 FROM friends WHERE username1 LIKE 'SOMETHING';
```

Can i do it in one query somehow?

Comment: Yes you can. Use "or" operator:

    SELECT username1,username2  FROM friends WHERE username1 LIKE 'SOMETHING' or username2 LIKE 'SOMETHING';

Comment: Take a look at the UNION operator.

Answer (score 1):

**UNION**

```
SELECT username1 AS name, '1' AS source FROM friends WHERE username2 LIKE 'SOMETHING'
UNION
SELECT username2, '2' FROM friends WHERE username1 LIKE 'SOMETHING';
```

Maybe with an extra column of the source.